# Is it correct to say "il lago di Loch Ness"?

Tags: foreign-words

I often hear people referring to Loch Ness, as *il lago di Loch Ness*.

However *Loch* is the Scottish for *Lago*, so it appears to be redundant.

Consider the two sentences

> Si racconta che un mostro viva nel lago di Loch Ness

and

> Si racconta che un mostro viva in Loch Ness

The second one sounds awkward, and I wasn't even sure whether to put *in*, *a*, or *nel*.

Which one would be, grammatically-wise, more appropriate?

Comment: The second example is appears to be incorrect, if you want to use loch as "lago", then the correct Italian would be: "Si racconta che un mostro viva nel loch Ness" (loch becomes lower case and takes a determinative article because it's not a proper name anymore)

Comment: Related: the same thing sometimes happen with _Monte Fuji_, sometimes incorrectly labeled as _Monte Fujiyama_, were _yama_ actually means _monte_.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Grammatically, I agree that adding *Loch* would make the sentence redundant, but I think that it may easily happen that the name of a place in a foreign language loses its original meaning.

In this sense, I would argue that for the average Italian *Loch Ness*, if not even *Lochness* is the name of the place, without any reference to it being a lake, so that adding the word for "lake" is felt as to be necessary.

Of course this depends on how much the speaker knows about the particular toponym.

Comment: Conversely, English speakers sometimes do the same with Italian words. For instance, when saying *minestrone soup*. I guess the issue just lays in the fact that not many Italians know *Loch* means lake...

Comment: Sure, this happens in every language with borrowings. Indeed, not many foreigners know the meanings of the words they write on the so-called "Italian restaurants" menus.

Comment: This is also common with abbreviations, the most famous one being AC Current

Comment: In english they say: let's meet at "Piazza Navona square", which create exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

It's not specific only to Italian, actually. Once the name of a place becomes widely known in its "inseparable" form, it's often used as a proper name, without reference to its actual meaning. Particularly, the situation is the same in English (*The monster lives in Loch Ness*, not The Monster lives in the Lake of Ness), German (*Das Ungeheuer lebt in Loch Ness*), and French (*Le monstre vit dans le Loch Ness*).
In Spanish, though, the name of the lake is separated and translated appropriately: *Una criatura legendaria habita en el lago Ness*.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware that *Loch* means a lake, so the second sentence seems to me as if the monster lived in the *town* of *Loch Ness*. I'd suggest to use the first one as more used.